# Does your choice of animal avatar have any effect on the game?

Tags: zookeeper-battle

I've recently started playing [Zookeeper Battle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.kiteretsu.zookeeperbattle.google) on my Android phone

I wondered whether the choice of animal you play makes any difference? Do you perhaps gain extra points if you match the same kind of animal that you are currently playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I've tried suggests that it makes no difference which animal you play as.